# Passing vector and single values to function with pmap

Tags: r, purrr

Getting my feet wet with purrr.

I'm evaluating different combinations of parameters for a beta distribution and I'm trying to pass a vector of x values and the parameters for the distribution.

See the code below:

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

x <- seq(0.01, 0.99, 0.01)
alpha <-  c(0.1, 0.5, 1:5, 10)
beta <-  c(0.5, 1, 2, 5)


df <- expand.grid(alpha = alpha, beta = beta, x = x) %>% 
  nest(x) %>%
  mutate(plotdata = pmap(list(data$x, alpha, beta), dbeta)) %>%
  unnest()
```

What's the right syntax for pmap in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Let's get the first case as an example.

```
 x = 0.01
 alpha = 0.1
 beta = 0.5

dbeta(shape1 = alpha, shape2 = beta, x = x)
# [1] 5.600381
```

A second example would be:

```
x = 0.01
alpha = 0.5  
beta = 0.5 

dbeta(shape1 = alpha, shape2 = beta, x = x)
# [1] 3.199135
```

If this is the output you are expecting, then we could generalize it:

```
x <- seq(0.01, 0.99, 0.01)
alpha <-  c(0.1, 0.5, 1:5, 10)
beta <-  c(0.5, 1, 2, 5)

df <- expand.grid(alpha = alpha, beta = beta, x = x)

args_beta <- with(df, list(x = x, shape1 = alpha, shape2 = beta))
args_beta %>% 
  pmap(dbeta) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  cbind(df, .)
```

Then the output would be:

```
alpha beta    x            .
1   0.1  0.5 0.01 5.600381e+00
2   0.5  0.5 0.01 3.199135e+00
3   1.0  0.5 0.01 5.025189e-01
4   2.0  0.5 0.01 7.537784e-03
5   3.0  0.5 0.01 9.422230e-05
6   4.0  0.5 0.01 1.099260e-06
```

Comment: Thanks! But this is not giving me what I need.

The result should be a data frame with 3168 rows = length(x) * length(alpha) * length(beta)

Comment: If you are taking the time to answer a question please go a step further and explain it, not only to help the OP but also to help everyone else that might get to this page with the same question. Bear in mind that not everyone has the same background and understanding. Your question was flagged as `low quality`, please take some time to improve it.